# changing sunit and swidth in XFS without data loss

Tags: raid, nfs, xfs

we have a medium sized scientific cluster with 32 compute nodes. The head node serves a 54TB storage that is RAID-6. It is consisted of 22 3TB HDDs (2 Parity units) and stripe size of 256K. The NFS is /home. We have been experiencing poor I/O performance lately. When I execute `xfs_info /home`
I see the following

```
meta-data=/dev/sdb1              isize=256    agcount=55, agsize=268435455 blks
         =                       sectsz=512   attr=2, projid32bit=0
         =                       crc=0        finobt=0 spinodes=0
data     =                       bsize=4096   blocks=14648380928, imaxpct=1
         =                       sunit=0      swidth=0 blks
naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0 ftype=0
log      =internal               bsize=4096   blocks=521728, version=2
         =                       sectsz=512   sunit=0 blks, lazy-count=1
realtime =none                   extsz=4096   blocks=0, rtextents=0
```

Somebody pointed out the sunit and swidth should match RAID config. In our case sunit must be 256K and swidth must be 20. The only way I can reset these values is through mkfs.xfs, apparently. However, I am a bit hesitant to do so, I am afraid of losing users data

My question is: Is it possible that I lose user data reconfiguring partition table using mkfs.xfs? What is the safest way to change sunit and swidth?

I would appreciate your comments and suggestions

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible that I lose user data reconfiguring partition table using mkfs.xfs?

Yes, in fact that is literally what `mkfs` tools do: they always create a brand new filesystem with no data in it. (Commonly called "reformatting".) So if you run mkfs on a partition with existing filesystem, data loss is 100% likely.

> What is the safest way to change sunit and swidth?

If the official live-reconfiguration tools such as `xfs_admin` do not allow changing this, then it's best to assume the only way you can change it is by 1) making a backup, 2) re-creating the filesystem from scratch, 3) restoring from backup.

There are tools such as `fstransform` which can rebuild an existing filesystem – it's meant for converting between different filesystem types, but it could just as well "convert" old XFS to new XFS. However, it still seems like a risky operation and you would want to have a backup *anyway*, so I would still go with the "backup and rebuild" route.